# How do I send coverage data from Istanbul to Coveralls.io?

Tags: node.js, windows, istanbul, coveralls

Here's the situation: I'm a complete n00b at Node.js and I'm working on my first package. The repo is set up on GitHub, I've created some working tests with Mocha, and I've also added it to Travis CI. Just now, I struck upon the code to use [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) through Mocha.

The problem is that though I've been trying all day to set up a system that communicates the Istanbul data to Coveralls.io, I just can't figure it out. I've tried using the [node-coveralls](https://github.com/nickmerwin/node-coveralls) package, which gives this example script:

```
istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --report lcovonly -- -R spec && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js && rm -rf ./coverage
```

However, as I'm on a Windows computer, I don't have the `cat` command. As I'm also a complete n00b at writing scripts, I googled and experimented for an hour and came up with this:

```
istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --report lcovonly -- -R spec && ./coverage/lcov.info > ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js 2>&1 && rm -rf ./coverage
```

I'm not exactly sure whether this pipes the output to `coveralls.js` or if it *appends* the output instead. It didn't error, so I tried pushing it, but it failed every Node version on Travis CI.

Also, the Coveralls page for my repo is still on the "Set up Coveralls for Ruby + Travis CI" page. I've created a `.coveralls.yml` file, but it's currently empty. So I guess I have two questions:

1. How can I set up a system on Windows for piping Istanbul data to node-coveralls?
2. Do I *need* to put my repo token in the `.coveralls.yml` file for it to register? I'm pretty sure I don't, because Coveralls stresses keeping tokens private.

If there's a basic Node package hosted on GitHub that uses Mocha + Istanbul + Coveralls, I'd love to just be able to look at how that's set up.

One more thing: I'm not sure where exactly in the repo I need to put the script. Does it go in the `after-success` section in `.travis.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully integrated it by using https://github.com/pimterry/grunt-coveralls

I have added `.coveralls.yml` with token as `repo_token: xKfOF1Cr********`
then I give the config in grunt file as as

```
ci_cd: {
      // LCOV coverage file (can be string, glob or array)
      src: 'coverage/server/unit/*.info',
      options: {
        // Any options for just this target
      }
    }
```

where src refer to the info file generated by istanbul